# Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to int

Tags: java, android, int, void

```
public int countContacts() {
    String query = "select count(name) from contacts";
    int count = db1.execSQL(query);           //  I got error at this line
    return count;

}
```

I was trying to count the number of rows in a table by using the above code. But I got this error- "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to int". Why I got this error and how can I correct it ?

---

UPDATE :

db1 is SQLiteDatabase.

I use Eclipse for coding. I got this error while I was coding. I didn't even run the code.

Comment: What type db1 have? Did you read JavaDoc?

Comment: what is db1? can you please paste the complete code? if its a preparedStatement, you need to call executeUpdate not executeQuery

Comment: @talex What you mean by type of db1 ?

Comment: Can you add error detail?

Comment: @Manu Jacob every variable have a type associated with it. You specify it when declare variable.

Comment: @MindPeace I use Eclipse for coding. I got this error while I was coding. I didn't even run the code.

Comment: Suppose you using `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase`. JavaDocis here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use execSQL to `select`.

From the [Android SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for SQLiteDatabase:

> execSQL(String sql): Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a
>   SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

You can try:

```
    //Query
    String query = "select COUNT from contacts where name = ?";
    Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(query, new String[] {name});
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // title Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return 0;
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COUNT"));
    cursor.close();
    return count;
```

Comment: Does this code return the number of rows ?

Comment: Yes. Selecting COUNT should return the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rawQuery` instead.

Or `compileStatement(sql).simpleQueryForLong()`